# how to make R script stop when it has to read a line?

Tags: r, readline, interaction, rscript

I want this code to ask for the value of `x` while I run the whole script but it doesn't wait for the input. Although it waits for a file to get uploaded by the user at line 3. While running it line by line this works fine and that is obvious. What is the best method to this?

```
x = readline("how many columns?")
Data = read.csv(file.choose())
columns = matrix(rep(0, dim(Data[1] * x), nrow = dim(Data)[1]))
Data = cbind(Data, columns)
```

Answer (score 3):

because when you run whole the script, it can't wait to get the **x** value.
You can put the script into a function, then call the function.
It will run line by line.

```
your_func_name <- function()
{
     #your script
}
```

Whenever you wanna call the script:

```
#just call the function
your_func_name()
```

Comment: Plus one - I didn't knew that!